# Confusion opening file inside of tkinter with askopenfilename

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, data-analysis

I'm trying to cerate a data retrieval program that is user friendly.  I have created a simple GUI that when a user clicks on "file" -> "new" -> browse files. They should be able to open the .multi file in the GUI. All of the buttons work and file explorer opens to search for files, however after choosing a .multi file and opening it nothing happens. I don't get an error code, and I don't know what happened to the file I just opened.

What I would like to happen is the .multi file get 'saved/stored' (I'm not sure if this is correct syntax) in the GUI.  Then when a user imports a script from "script"->"browse" (also inside the GUI) the script will parse the file that was just imported and plot whatever parameters are set up in the script.

MY QUESTIONS IS THIS: What happens to the file when I open it? and how can I get it to be saved/stored inside the GUI until the script can parse it for data?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, Toplevel
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror 

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT= ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT= ("Verdana", 8)
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.style.use("seaborn-bright")

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.wm_title("Menu")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()
```

Here is where I think the problem is, seeing as I'm unsure whether or not my file was actually loaded, because I didn't receive an error code or any indication that it was loaded.

```
def load_file(self):
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("All files", "*.*"),
                                           ('Python files', '*.py*'),
                                           ('Multi files', '*.multi*')))

class PyWinProject(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "TkGraph")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: load_file(self))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Add", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        scriptmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        scriptmenu.add_command(label="Browse", command = lambda: load_file(self))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Script", menu=scriptmenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        parameter = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        parameter.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Parameter", menu=parameter)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        timemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        timemenu.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Time", menu=timemenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(StartPage)
            def show_frame(self, cont):
                frame = self.frames[cont]
                frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        fig = plt.figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()

        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

app = PyWinProject()
app.mainloop()
```

****Update: I have added this line to my code after `def load_file(self):`

```
 if fname:
        try:
            fname.open()
        except:                     
            showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
        return
```

And this returns: "Failed to read file" as expected. So why cant python read the file?

This is the full error report from python:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.......\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-34-3810935f52b9>", line 68, in <lambda>
    filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: load_file(self))
  File "<ipython-input-34-3810935f52b9>", line 52, in load_file
    return fname.open()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: The exception will tell you why it failed to read. You should examine the error and provide it as part of your question.

Comment: @Brian I've added the full error report in my question.

Comment: `fname.open()` should be `open(fname)`.